# CMUS is not working on 15.10

Tags: cmus

I've been using 14.04 LTS for the last few weeks and have just updated to 15.10
CMUS had been working fine on 14.04, but ever since I upgraded, it just doesn't work.

I've installed and removed cmus several times, but I can't get it to start.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu 15.10. I guess that there  aren't many cmus users to notice these things.

Answer (score 2):

One of the `cmus` dependencies starts a network server that causes `cmus` to hang while it never loads. The following resolves the issue:

```
$ apt-get purge libdnet dnet-common
```

You can perform a fresh `cmus` install without the server as so:

```
$ sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install cmus cmus-plugin-ffmpeg
```

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cmus/+bug/923027) is the related bug report.